# What does the ^ (XOR) operator do?

Tags: math, operators

What mathematical operation does XOR perform?

Comment: XOR is **logical** operation, not a mathematical.

Answer (score 163):

XOR is a binary operation, it stands for "exclusive or", that is to say the resulting bit evaluates to one if only exactly *one* of the bits is set.

This is its function table:

```
a | b | a ^ b
--|---|------
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

This operation is performed between every two corresponding bits of a number.

Example: `7 ^ 10`
In binary: `0111 ^ 1010`

```
  0111
^ 1010
======
  1101 = 13
```

**Properties:** The operation is commutative, associative and self-inverse.

It is also the same as addition modulo 2.

Comment: Man, that is really so very simple! I'm working through understanding hash algorithms more and this is a very constant operation among many of them.

Comment: It is also the same as addition modulo 2. - What is meant by this?

Comment: @RajaDorji Explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41664/confused-about-xoring-and-addition-modulo-2)

Answer (score 56):

`^` *is* the [Python bitwise XOR operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations). It is how you spell `XOR` in python:

```
>>> 0 ^ 0
0
>>> 0 ^ 1
1
>>> 1 ^ 0
1
>>> 1 ^ 1
0
```

XOR stands for [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). It is used in cryptography because it let's you 'flip' the bits using a mask in a reversable operation:

```
>>> 10 ^ 5
15
>>> 15 ^ 5
10
```

where `5` is the mask; *(input XOR mask) XOR mask* gives you the input again.

Comment: The truth table speaks the truth - and in conversation I usually describe XOR (eXclusive-OR, sometimes also known as EOR) as 'either A or B, but not both or neither'.

Comment: Thank you!!! You and the other respondent have surely saved my sanity for the day --- I simply could NOT figure it out and it was so un-google-able.

Answer (score 17):

A little more information on XOR operation.

- XOR a number with itself odd number of times the result is number
  itself.
- XOR a number even number of times with itself, the result is 0.
- Also XOR with 0 is always the number itself.

Answer (score 6):

One thing that other answers don't mention here is **XOR with negative numbers** -

```
 a  |  b  | a ^ b
----|-----|------
 0  |  0  |  0
 0  |  1  |  1
 1  |  0  |  1
 1  |  1  |  0
```

While you could easily understand how XOR will work using the above functional table, it doesn't tell how it will work on negative numbers.

---

## How XOR works with Negative Numbers :

Since this question is also tagged as python, I will be answering it with that in mind. The **XOR ( `^` ) is an logical operator** that will return 1 when the bits are different and 0 elsewhere.

A negative number is stored in binary as **[two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)**. In 2's complement, The leftmost bit position is reserved for the sign of the value (positive or negative) and doesn't contribute towards the value of number.

> In, [Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators), negative numbers are written with a leading one instead of a leading
>   zero. So if you are using only 8 bits for your *two's-complement*
>   numbers, then you treat patterns from `00000000` to `01111111` as the
>   whole numbers from 0 to 127, and reserve `1xxxxxxx` for writing negative
>   numbers.

With that in mind, lets understand how XOR works on negative number with an example. Lets consider the expression - `( -5 ^ -3 )` .

- The binary representation of `-5` can be considered as `1000...101` and
- Binary representation of `-3` can be considered as `1000...011`.

Here, `...` denotes all 0s, the number of which depends on bits used for representation (32-bit, 64-bit, etc). The `1` at the **MSB** ( Most Significant Bit ) denotes that the number represented by the binary representation is negative. The XOR operation will be done on all bits as usual.

### XOR Operation :

```
      -5   :  10000101          |
     ^                          | 
      -3   :  10000011          |  
    ===================         |
    Result :  00000110  =  6    |
________________________________|


     ∴ -5 ^ -3 = 6
```

Since, the MSB becomes 0 after the XOR operation, so the resultant number we get is a positive number. Similarly, for all negative numbers, we consider their representation in binary format using *2's complement* (one of most commonly used) and do simple XOR on their binary representation.

#### The **MSB bit of result will denote the sign** and the **rest of the bits will denote the value**  of the final result.

The following table could be useful in determining the sign of result.

```
  a   |   b   | a ^ b
------|-------|------
  +   |   +   |   +
  +   |   -   |   -
  -   |   +   |   -
  -   |   -   |   +
```

The basic rules of XOR remains same for negative XOR operations as well, but how the operation really works in negative numbers could be useful for someone someday .

Answer (score 4):

Another application for `XOR` is in circuits. It is used to sum bits.

When you look at a truth table:

```
 x | y | x^y
---|---|-----
 0 | 0 |  0     // 0 plus 0 = 0 
 0 | 1 |  1     // 0 plus 1 = 1
 1 | 0 |  1     // 1 plus 0 = 1
 1 | 1 |  0     // 1 plus 1 = 0 ; binary math with 1 bit
```

You can notice that the result of `XOR` is x added with y, without keeping track of the carry bit, the carry bit is obtained from the `AND` between x and y.

```
x^y // is actually ~xy + ~yx
    // Which is the (negated x ANDed with y) OR ( negated y ANDed with x ).
```

Answer (score 3):

The (^) XOR operator generates 1 when it is applied on two different bits (0 and 1). It generates 0 when it is applied on two same bits (0 and 0 or 1 and 1).