# overloading bitwise operator XOR

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rounding

As I finish working on my Money Class project, I am left with one instruction and that is using the bitwise operator ^ to round-off two Money objects.

In my header file I have:

```
#ifndef MONEY_H
#define MONEY_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Money{
    public:
        Money(int dollars, int cents);
        Money(int dollars);
        Money();
        int getDollars() const {return dollars;};
        int getCents() const {return cents;};
        void setDollarsAndCents(int dollars, int cents);
        double getAmount() const {return dollars + cents / 100.0    ;};
        void setAmount(double amount);

        //Define bit wise operator
        friend Money operator^(const Money& firstAmount, const Money& secondAmount);

        //Define the input and output operator
        friend istream& operator>>(istream& inputStream, const Money& money);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& outStream, const Money& money);

    private:
        int dollars, cents;
        double amount;
};

const Money LOONIE = Money(1 , 0);
const Money TOONIE = Money(2 , 0);
const Money QUARTER = Money(0 , 25);
const Money DIME = Money(0 , 10);
const Money NICKEL = Money(0 , 5);
#endif
```

And in my implementation file:

```
    #include "Money.h"

// Construct a money object with dollars and cents
Money::Money(int newDollars, int newCents)
{
    dollars = newDollars;
    cents = newCents;
    amount = dollars + cents/100.0;
}
// Construct a money object with JUST the dollars
Money::Money(int newDollars)
{
    dollars = newDollars;
    cents = 0;
    amount = dollars + cents;
}
// Construct a money object with no arguments (default amount = 0)
Money::Money()
{
    amount = 0.0;
}
// Set dollars and cents
void Money::setDollarsAndCents(int newDollars, int newCents)
{
    dollars = newDollars;
    cents = newCents;
    amount = dollars + cents/100.0;
}
// Set monetary amount
void Money::setAmount(double newAmount)
{
    amount = newAmount;
}

// Round up first Money object to the nearest second Money object
Money operator^(const Money& firstAmount, const Money& secondAmount)
{
    int finalDollars = firstAmount.dollars + secondAmount.dollars); 
    firstAmount.cents += secondAmount.cents/2; 
    return Money(finalDollars, ((firstAmount.cents/secondAmount.cents)*secondAmount.cents));
}
// Define the input operator
istream& operator>>(istream& inputStream, const Money& money)
{
    inputStream >> money.dollars >> money.cents;
    return inputStream;
}
// Define the output operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, const Money& money)
{
    outputStream << money.dollars << "." << money.cents;
   return outputStream;
}
```

Note: I don't think I need to do `int finalDollars` since I'm not rounding off to the nearest dollar.

Finally in my main:

```
 #include "Money.h"

int main()
{

    //Test round-off operator ^
    Money m14(4 , 19); //round off to the nearest nickel : $4.19 = $4.20
    cout << (m14 ^ NICKEL) << endl;
    Money m15(-3, -1); //round off to the nearest nickel : $-3.01 = $-3.00
    cout << (m15 ^ NICKEL) << endl;

    return 0;
}

Output: 4.22
       -2.-106
```

EDIT: Got  too excited that I forgot the question

If  anyone  could help me show what is wrong and why I'm getting the wrong output, that would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnKugelman  editted: sorry about that!

Comment: @ArcRanges Well, you're still missing to provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so sorry for all the mess. everything should be there now.

Comment: Basically this: `unsigned int finalCents = (firstAmount.cents ^ secondAmount.cents);` doesn't make sense for rounding.  Do you know what the xor operator does?

Comment: @MichaelBurr can you  please enlighten me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14526584/12711

Comment: @ArcRanges, your last edit is not appropriate. The answers to the original post will not make sense any more.

Comment: @RSahu Just tried eigenchris' approach, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArcRanges, Did you see my comment to your comment to my answer?

Comment: @RSahu I did. I tried it too and it doesn't work. I'll edit the code using yours.

Comment: @ArcRanges, when you edit your post, please leave the original as is. Add updates to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you thought

```
unsigned int finalCents = (firstAmount.cents ^ secondAmount.cents);
```

will give you the closest pennies.

This works for me:

```
int closestPennies(int cents1, int cents2)
{
   cents1 += cents2/2;
   return (cents1/cents2)*cents2;
}
```

Here's a sample program and the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int closestPennies(int cents1, int cents2)
{
   cents1 += cents2/2;
   return (cents1/cents2)*cents2;
}

void printClosestPennies(int cents1, int cents2)
{
   int closest = closestPennies(cents1, cents2);
   printf("Cents 1: %d, Cents 2: %d, Closest Cents: %d\n",
          cents1, cents2, closest);
}

int main()
{
   printClosestPennies(21, 5);
   printClosestPennies(26, 5);
   printClosestPennies(29, 5);
   printClosestPennies(21, 10);
   printClosestPennies(26, 10);
   printClosestPennies(29, 10);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Cents 1: 21, Cents 2: 5, Closest Cents: 20
Cents 1: 26, Cents 2: 5, Closest Cents: 25
Cents 1: 29, Cents 2: 5, Closest Cents: 30
Cents 1: 21, Cents 2: 10, Closest Cents: 20
Cents 1: 26, Cents 2: 10, Closest Cents: 30
Cents 1: 29, Cents 2: 10, Closest Cents: 30
```

Comment: tried your approach : int finalDollars = firstAmount.dollars + secondAmount.dollars);
 firstAmount.cents += secondAmount.cents/2;
 return Money(finalDollars, ((firstAmount.cents/secondAmount.cents)*firstAmount.cents)); no luck.

Comment: The last term is not right. It needs to be `secondAmount.cents`.

Comment: I tried, still doesn't work.. :(

Comment: @ArcRanges, don't know how to help further. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `^` operator is doing what you expect it to. Let's take your first example.

```
Money m14(4 , 19); //round off to the nearest nickel : $4.19 = $4.20
cout << (m14 ^ NICKEL) << endl;
```

Evaluating `firstAmount.cents ^ secondAmount.cents` gives us `19^5`. If we look at the bitwise XOR in binary...

```
0000 0101 <-- five
0001 0011 <-- nineteen
0001 0110 <-- XOR = twenty-two
```

So you end up getting `4.22` as your output.

---

A simple solution to your problem is using modular arithmetic with `%`. We can check the remainder of `19/5` using `19%5`. If the result is greater than or equal to `5/2`, we round up (add the difference between the `5` and remainder), if not, we round down (subtract the remainder).

`19%5==4` and `4>5/2` so we round up using `19 + 5 - 4` to get `20`.

In general, given `x` cents and some coin value `c`, we can round as follows:

```
int r = x%c;     // get remainder
if (r >= c/2) {
    x += c - r;  // round up
} else {
    x -= r;      // round down
}
```

In this case `x` would be `firstAmount.cents` and `c` would be `secondAmount.cents`.

Comment: I understand now. Could you guide me how to fix that so I could get $4.20?

Comment: @ArcRanges I added a solution.

Comment: I tried implementing your code: no luck. I guess I suck at following instructions. editted post for implementing your code.

Comment: @ArcRanges I got the same results R Sahu got with his test cases. What goes wrong on your end. Do you get an error message, or just wrong results?

Comment: I think the program does not recognize the operator overloading for ^.  It just keeps using the  bitwise function  not the function being implemented.

Comment: but then it will have to be one argument only.

Comment: Sorry, I see that's not the problem. I'm not sure what the problem is.