# Unable to understand the logic behind `XOR` when finding the missing value in an array

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

Here is the sample of code, which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113795/quickest-way-to-find-missing-number-in-an-array-of-numbers).

```
public class Snippet {
    private static final int[] ARRAY = {1, 4, 3, 18, 2, 8, 9, 6, 5, 10,
            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 0, 20};

    //{1,2,4,5,6,8,7,9,3}
    private int getMissingElem() {
        int XOR = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (ARRAY[i] != 0) {
                XOR ^= ARRAY[i];
            }
            XOR ^= (i + 1);
        }
        return XOR;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snippet s = new Snippet();
        System.out.println(s.getMissingElem());
    }
}
```

I just came to know about how, `XOR` have the values of missing elements of array.

Comment: https://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/java-bitwise-xor.shtml << This explanation of java's XOR operator comes up by googling "Java XOR"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the ^ (XOR) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526584/what-does-the-xor-operator-do). This is for a question in python, but the XOR operator reacts the same in Python or Java.

Comment: Note your code only works if the array contains integers 1 to `ARRAY.length` except one integer becomes 0.

Comment: There is no need to check if the number is non-zero before xor. `a ^ 0 = a`.

Answer (score 7):

XOR is *bitwise*. That means, given two integer values `a, b`, `a ^ b` has a `1` bit on that position if and only if either that position of `a` or `b`  is `1`, but not both.

The value 15 would be bitwise (with 8 bits here, for simplicity) represented as `00001111`, whereas the value 60 would be bitwise represented as `00111100`. Note that `15 ^ 60` would equal `00110011`, because bits 2-3 equals `1` for both 15 only, and bits 6-7 equals `0` for 60 only.

**For your question regarding finding the missing element of an array**, it only works if the array otherwise contains integers 1 to `ARRAY.length` except that one integer is 0 (Precondition).

- Notice that XOR is commutative and associative. That means, `a ^ b ==
  b ^ a`, and `(a ^ b) ^ c == a ^ (b ^ c) == a ^ b ^ c)`
- for all `a, b, c`. Also, if you XOR the same number twice, it cancels
  out, and the result becomes 0. Given any number `n`, `n ^ n == 0`, also `a ^ n ^ n == a`.
- For all `a`, `a ^ 0 == a` because if this bit of `a` is `1`, exactly one bit in that position is `1`.

The logic behind your XOR-based solution is that in that for all numbers that are included in this array, you performed XOR on that same number twice, which cancels out. The only exception is the missing number `n`, as 0 ^ `n` equals `n`.

Suppose `ARRAY` is an array that meets the precondition:

- Case 1: number `m` appears in array. The condition (*) for performing that XOR is when the loop is at the `i`th position such `ARRAY[i] == m` or at the `m - 1`th position. We have `XOR ^ m` when the condition is met the first time. As the loop progresses, the same condition is met again, so we have `XOR ^ m ^ k ^ m == XOR ^ (m ^ m) ^ k == XOR ^ k`, where `k` is the result of XORing the number between the first and second indices where the condition holds.
- Case 2: number `n`is missing from the array. Notice that the previous condition (*) is met only once while you iterate through the loop. We therefore have `XOR ^ n`.
- Because XOR is commutative and associative, we eventually get a final result of `XOR == a^a^b^b^...^n...^x^x^y^y`. Notice all the numbers except `n` is XORed twice as the loop finishes, we have `(a^a)^(b^b)^...^n^(x^x)^(y^y) == 0^0^...^n^...0^0`, hence we obtained `n` as desired.