# what does the ^= operator mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

What does the `^=` operator mean in Python?

I check online and it says "Performs Bitwise xOR on operands and assign value to left operand".

I played around and I am still confused. Could anyone enlighten with some examples?

Comment: `x ^= y` means `x = x^y`. Then see [What does the ^ (XOR) operator do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526584/what-does-the-xor-operator-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XOR will returns true when only ODD numbers of conditions are TRUE.

Assuming the following cases:

```
Condition A: False; Condition B: False =>  A XOR B = False
Condition A: False; Condition B: True => A XOR B = True
Condition A: True; Condition B: False => A XOR B = True
Condition A: True; Condition B: True => A XOR B = False
```

So lets say we have the following code:

```
a = True
b = True
b ^= a #b XOR a
print(b) #Result = False

c = True
d = False
d ^= c #d XOR c
print(d) #Result = True
```

To answer khelwood's comment on this answer;

You must first know binary (base-2) system. So lets have example number 6 and number 3. These numbers converts to 0110 and 0011 in base-2 respectively. When we perform XOR on the numbers, we will perform the operations on each individual bits.

Let the bits in the order of b3, b2, b1, b0.
In b3 place, 0 XOR 0 will gives you 0
In b2 place, 1 XOR 0 will give you 1
In b1 place, 1 XOR 1 will give you 0
In b0 place, 0 XOR 1 will give you 1.

Hence, the result is 0101 in base-2, which is 5 in base-10

```
a = 6
b = 3
b ^= a
print(b) #Result = 5
```

Comment: Pretty sure you meant d ^= c IS true, d is a different boolean value than c

Comment: @khelwood edited the answers to answer your question.

Comment: @ec2604 Sorry, typo on my part!