# Why in Python 3.6 print(-5 ^ -3) is 6?

Tags: python, python-3.6

In the Notebook of Google Colaboratory, whose version is python 3.6 by putting the following syntax - `print(-5 ^ -3)`,  I have the result as `6`. I want to know why I get this result and how python interprets it.

**Edit :** This question is not a dupe of other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526584/what-does-the-xor-operator-do) because that question is just general explanation of bitwise XOR operation and doesn't explain how bitwise operation works with negative numbers ( in python ).

Answer (score 2):

> Negative numbers are written with a leading one instead of a leading
>   zero. So if you are using only 8 bits for your twos-complement
>   numbers, then you treat patterns from `00000000` to `01111111` as the
>   whole numbers from 0 to 127, and reserve `1xxxxxxx` for writing
>   negative numbers. ([source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators))

---

#### Explanation :

The statement `print(-5^-3)` will basically perform **bitwise-XOR** operation of -5 and -3 and print their result. Lets see the binary representation of these two numbers

The binary representation of -5 can be considered as `1000...101` and binary representation of -3 can be considered as `1000...011`. Here `1` at the MSB ( Most Significant Bit ) denotes that the number represented by the binary representation is negative.

So Xor will return 1 only if two bits are of opposite ( 1 and 0 ). Here's how xor will work considering 8-bit representation of the numbers.

### XOR Operation :

```
  -5   :  10000101
 ^ 
  -3   :  10000011
----------------------
Result :  00000110
```

And `00000110` in binary representation is considered as 6 in decimals. Hence, the answer that gets printed is 6.

Hope this helps !